# While Loop Won't Break?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is just a quick little code task for school, but I've been testing and changing all the possible ways the condition could be and nothing works. The while loop just continues to run past 9 turns, which it shouldn't be doing. It's such a simple while loop yet it doesn't break and it's really confusing me. I'm probably being super dumb but please help.

```
def main():
    turns=0
    while turns<9:
        print("Turns:",turns)
        print_grid()
        p1()
        turns+=1
        print("Turns:",turns)
        print_grid()
        p2()
        turns+=1
    print("done")
main()
```

There are obviously unecessary print statements, they're just the ones I was using to check the turns to make sure I wasnt being stupid. This is the most basic way I can tell it to continue to loop until turns equals 9, which when the code runs, it literally tells me in IDLE - "Turns: 9" which just angers me further. I cant input further than 9 due to the rest of the code not allowing further inputs.

Comment: where is the function **print_grid()**?

Comment: That's confusing, every other time I've used while loops this was never a problem. Anyhow, any idea on how to fix that? Because I can't just add 2 turns at the end of both player's turns because the maximum number of turns is 9, and that wouldn't make sense logically because I'd have to begin the loop at 8 and end at 10, and we'd be at the same problem again.

Comment: ```def print_grid():
    for x in range(0,9):
        if x%3==0:
            print("")
        print("|"+str(grid[x])+"|",end="")```               This procedure is above, the code, it runs fine, no worries.

Comment: Yea I just duplicated it for testing reasons, but I fixed it with a simple if statement, turns out I was just being dumb. Thanks for the range suggestion, that is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the `while` loop is only checked before each iteration runs. If `turns` becomes greater than `9` at some point in the middle of the loop, the loop will not break half way through an iteration. If you want it to `break` in the middle, you need to manually check that:

```
while turns<9:
    print("Turns:",turns)
    print_grid()
    p1()
    turns+=1
    if turns >= 9:  # Check here
        break
    print("Turns:",turns)
    print_grid()
    p2()
    turns+=1
```

This is messy though. Most of that loop is duplicated. The only thing that changes is the call to `p1` and `p2`. I'd just toggle between the two functions, and change from a `while` to a `range`:

```
func = p1
for turn in range(9):
    print("Turns:", turn)
    print_grid()
    func()  # Call p1 or p2 depending

    if func is p1:  # Toggle
        func = p2
    else:
        func = p1
```

That end part can be changed to this as well:

```
func = p2 if func is p1 else p1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing function **print_grid** but from your description I think what you need is this

```
def main():
    turns=0
    while turns<9:
        print("Turns:",turns)
        turns+=1 # to iterate and print turns, it should be after **print**
    print("done")
main()
```

output

```
Turns: 0
Turns: 1
Turns: 2
Turns: 3
Turns: 4
Turns: 5
Turns: 6
Turns: 7
Turns: 8
done
```

Comment: Yea that would be the logical way of thinking about it but thats impossible due to the nature of the rest of the code. This would be easy and correct if i only had one player adding turns to it, but instead I have two, which made the turns even after each iteration, whereas I had to have it break at an odd value. It's alright though, I've fixed it by simply adding an if statement to check if the turns are less than 9. Turns out I was just having a brain fart. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: anyway the while loop won't stop if it could not reach the declared limit, so based on ur code, i think the main issue is to correctly place **turns+=1** to break the loop. else, nothing more could be interpreted with the actual code. you gotta optimize it before mods delete it for missing focus.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably convert that `while` loop into a `for` loop as it's better for your usecase but let me explain what happens anyway.

During your loop, you increment `turns` after you loop begins, so it will go up to 9, and THEN break. What you can do to fix that is change the code from `while turns < 9` to `while turns != 8` or introduce an if statement

```
if turns == 8:
    break
```

Then again, I suggest you change it into a `for` loop:

```
def main():
    turns=0
    for _ in range(8):
        print("Turns:",turns)
        print_grid()
        p1()
        turns+=1
        print("Turns:",turns)
        print_grid()
        p2()
        turns+=1
    print("done")
main()
```

EDIT: Like @CYREX said, you should also increment before printing, not after.